# Basic echo command in shell script not working in Mac

Tags: shell, scripting

I recently took a MacBook. I am trying to do some shell programs on my mac. I changed the shell to bash in my mac. When I started executing the shell scripts, I found `echo -n` is not working as expected. Please help me if I missed any particular settings or so...

In the terminal window (it is working fine):

```
$ echo "Hello.."
Hello..
$ echo -n "Hello.."
Hello..$
```

In test.sh file:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Hello.."
```

Output:

```
$ sh test.sh 
-n Hello..
```

Comment: If you want to use Bash features, use `bash test.sh` — running `sh test.sh` uses Bash in POSIX mode, which means many Bash features either don't work or don't work the same (always assuming `/bin/sh` is a link to `/bin/bash` or similar; if `/bin/sh` is a link to `/bin/dash` or another shell, you may get different behaviour again.  This is mostly explained in the duplicate question.

Comment: Thank you Benjamin. Got it.